# GAMS: How can I formulate the constraint $x_{a,i,v+1,l} - x_{a,i,v,l} \leq y_{a,i,v,l}$?

Tags: constraints, conditional-statements, gams-math

I am having issues with formulating a constraint in GAMS.

My constraint is as follows:

x_{a,i,v+1,l} - x_{a,i,v,l} \leq y_{a,i,v,l}

and sum(v,y_{a,i,v,l}) \leq 1.

I have tried to formulate it several times, but I think (Well I know) I am doing it wrong.

I wrote it in gams as :

con15(a,i,v,l)$(ord(v) lt 17).. x(a,i,v,l)$(ord(v) eq ord(v)+1) -
x(a,i,v,l) =l= u(a,i,v,l);

con16(a,i,l).. sum(v, u(a,i,v,l)) =l= 1;

a bit extra information:

i “employees” /i1*i11/

l “days” /l1*l31/

a “projects dependent on flightprogramme” /a1/

v “hour” /v1*v18/

In constraint con15 I say that it only should work for ord(v) less than or equal to 17, that is because we have v1 up to v18.

Also x and y are binary.

When I run GAMS I get normal compilation and a solution. The problem is that the solution violates my constraint con16 and con15.

Am I using ord and $ correct?

Best Husky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think you can use card() to make your equation con15 more general. This tells you the number of elements in a set.

Also, "lt" means strictly lower than. If you want to include the equality, you have to write "le".

I would try this:

con15(a,i,v,l)$(ord(v) lt card(v)).. x(a,i,v+1,l) - x(a,i,v,l) =l= u(a,i,v,l);

con16(a,i,l).. sum(v, u(a,i,v,l)) =l= 1;

I hope this helps.

Salva.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I encountered a similar problem in one of my own projects, I'm new to GAMS but hopefully this might help:

Turns out that ordered sets and adding values don't get along well: try to reformulate your problem to an equation with v-1 instead of v+1. Ordered sets start counting (and calculating) from a certain starting point and count(and calculate) until a defined end point: adding +1 to a point that has yet to be calculated caused issues to my model and might do the same for yours. Good luck!